# change the value of next pointed struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a pointer to struct:

```
typedef struct Tables_s
{
    uint8 type;                                 /*from StatisticType_e*/
    uint16 offset;                              /*offset from start of   buffer*/
} Tables_t;
```

that have member offset, and defined as :

```
Tables_t Table; 
Tables_t Table1;
```

then pointed with:

```
Tables_t *currTable;
currTable = Table;
```

this is one of many struct in an array:

```
arr[0] = &Table;
arr[1] = &Table1;
```

can I change the next struct in the list by doing the following?

```
(currTable+1)->offest
```

Comment: 1.) show code (the exact struct declaration and how it is used) 2.) show what you tried 3.) explain what didn't work as expected

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And then include, in the body of the question, why it doesn't work as you expect, and including what you expect and the actual results.

Comment: if currTable is pointing to a list you can

Comment: So what is missing to complete your question is the definition of `arr`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If `currTable` points to an element of an array of `Tables_t` (**not** `Tables_t*`) and it is not the last element in the array then accessing `cuurentTable + 1` is OK. You can also access it by `cuurentTable[1]`.

Array guarantees you that the structs are stored in continues memory.

**EDIT**

The question got updated with more details so I updated my answer below accordingly.

Since `currTable` points to `Table` which is a local variable (or even global) the `currTable + 1` is undefined.
In the case described in the question `currTable` should be `Tables_t**`:

```
Tables_t** currTable = arr;
```

Then

```
(*(currTable+1))->offset...
```

is legal.

**EDIT2**

Just a decoration/readability point:

```
(*(currTable+1))->offset...
```

is equivalent to

```
currTable[1]->offset...
```

which is more readable and intuitive (similarly to `arr` which can be used like `arr[1]->offset...`)

Comment: OK, but can i change the value of it member by doing :     (currTable+1)->offest  ???

Comment: @SionC I did not see you updated questions. With that implementation you cannot use `currentTable+1`. Because it ponts to Table and not arr [0]

Comment: @SionC, please take a look again at my answer after many typos and edits the beta release is here :). Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Ah, one last thing (which now is gone by deleting the comments): It might be worth mentioning that `(*(currTable+1))->offset` is equivalent to `currTable[1]->offset` and that this latter form is the preferred one, due to its readability (at least).

Comment: Agree, I had it in the first version of the answer and it makes sence to add it to the final answer as well. I'll update it.